# Magento 2 : Add wysiwyg editor in store configuration

Tags: magento2, wysiwyg, system-configuration

I want to add wysiwyg editor in store configuration. I added also. But, when I click on "**Insert Variable**" it's return error :

> **Uncaught ReferenceError: MagentovariablePlugin is not defined**

How to solve this error?

Any help would be appreciated !!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I found answer for that. Follow this below steps to solve this issue :

Add Field in **system.xml** file :

```
<field id="wysiwyg_editor" translate="wysiwyg" sortOrder="4" type="editor" showInStore="1" showInDefault="1" >
    <label>wysiwyg editor</label>
    <frontend_model>Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Editor</frontend_model>
</field>
```

Now, create file for add wysiwyg editor in element :

> app\code\Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Editor.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config;

use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config as WysiwygConfig;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;

class Editor extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
/**
* @var  Registry
*/
protected $_coreRegistry;
/**
* @param Context    $context
* @param WysiwygConfig $wysiwygConfig
* @param array      $data
*/


public function __construct(
     Context $context,
     WysiwygConfig $wysiwygConfig,
     array $data = []
) {
     $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
     parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
{
     // set wysiwyg for element
     $element->setWysiwyg(true);

     // set configuration values
     $element->setConfig($this->_wysiwygConfig->getConfig($element));

     return parent::_getElementHtml($element);
}
}
```

Now, create **adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml** for update editor handle :

> app\code\Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\layout\adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="editor"/>
</page>
```

**Clean cache and it's working.**

Comment: 1+...Thnk You..