# How to make field as WYSIWYG editor in system.xml in configuration?

Tags: magento2, wysiwyg, editor

I want to display editor not only textarea so please let me know what can I do here, and how to remove **Insert Widget** / **Insert Variable** / **Insert Image** button there?

```
<field id="gird_view" translate="label" type="textarea" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
   <label>Grid View Design</label>
</field>
```

Comment: Check this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/298409

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add this in your `system.xml` file

```
<field id="grid_view" translate="label comment" type="editor" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Grid View</label>
    <frontend_model>Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Editor</frontend_model>
</field>
```

Now create below Block file in your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Form/Field/Editor.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config as WysiwygConfig;

class Editor extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        WysiwygConfig $wysiwygConfig,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $element->setWysiwyg(true);
        $element->setConfig($this->_wysiwygConfig->getConfig(array('add_variables' => true, 'add_widgets' => false, 'add_images' => true)));
        return parent::_getElementHtml($element);
    }
}
```

Create below file in your module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="editor"/>
</page>
```

Run below command once

```
php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Perfect! Its works for me.

Comment: Hi for an editor it works fine but when I click on  Insert Variable then error comes as js "MagentovariablePlugin is not defined". If possible can you tell me this?

Comment: answer updated please review :)

Comment: It seems like you just copy answer from commented link and post here. Why you added already posted answer code?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya yes it works. now one more, how can remove that button Insert Widget, Insert Variable, Insert widget particular.

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel, Please let me know if it helps. Thanks. Check this file **app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Form/Field/Editor.php**

Comment: @KishanSavaliya yes it works but if I put add_images = false still that options come. is it default?

Comment: Yes, that is default. If you add false there then you can not get Add Images button there in editor. Please clear Magento cache once and check again.