# How to solve MagentovariablePlugin is not defined?

Tags: magento2, editor

Hi I am adding editor and its works perfectly but when I clicks on Insert variable I am facing this error.
**Error :-**

```
MagentovariablePlugin is not defined
```

My system.config  field code

```
<field id="grid_view" translate="label" type="editor" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
  <label>Grid View Design</label>
 <frontend_model>Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Editor</frontend_model>
</field>
```

and my Editor.php code

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config as WysiwygConfig;

class Editor extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        WysiwygConfig $wysiwygConfig,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $element->setWysiwyg(true);
        $element->setConfig($this->_wysiwygConfig->getConfig($element));
        return parent::_getElementHtml($element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a joke? I already added a link to your previous question. https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/298538/51810

Comment: @RohanHapani please tell me sir which question?

Comment: check above comment

Comment: @Rk Rathod I got an answer. thanks

Comment: add your answer @sarvesh Dineshkumar Patel

Comment: @Rohan Hapani sir I thought to create a new question for that. because before this I face same issue that is why I just added new one. I knew Kishan Savaliya given an answer just I was posted question. sorry sir if you mind it.

Comment: @Rohan Hapani  I just missed out on your link at that time.

Answer (score 0):

create **adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml** for update editor handle :

> app\code\Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\layout\adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="editor"/>
</page>
```

**Clean cache and it's working.**