# MagentovariablePlugin is not defined

Tags: magento2, wysiwyg

I'm adding wysiwyg editor in admin custom form [image]

All displays good and working fine, but when I click on Insert variable I have an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: MagentovariablePlugin is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create below file in your module

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml
```

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="editor"/>
</page>
```

And more information and most useful link :-

**[How to make field as WYSIWYG editor in system.xml in configuration?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298538/how-to-make-field-as-wysiwyg-editor-in-system-xml-in-configuration)**

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Comment: I tried to do it but it didn’t work...

Comment: you check attached link ???

Comment: I need to create app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Form/Field/Editor.php file to my editor? I can't understand how to indicate path to this block from my fieldset

Comment: you add `system.xml` file ???

Comment: This file need to add editor to configuration page, but I'm need to add editor in custom form. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: you are this `system.xml` file added or not ???

Comment: Yes, but it add editor in configuration page! i need to add editor in custom form!

Comment: I need to add this editor not in configuration page. System.xml add field in configuration page

Comment: Can you have any other ideas?

Comment: check this https://meetanshi.com/blog/add-wysiwyg-editor-in-magento-2-admin-form/ help or not ??? If No , Please post your code ...

Comment: It's not help me..